# How to add value of hlines in y axis using mplfinance python

Tags: python, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

Hello everyone and thank you for your help in advance. I have managed to plot a candlestick chart using mplfinance module in python and I have added some hlines to my plot. The problem is, I can't figure out how to add hlines value to yaxis of my chart.

here is my code:
`mpf.plot(hloc,hlines=dict(hlines=clusters_centers,colors=['blue'],linestyle='-.'), ylabel='Price', type='candle', style='binance')`

and this is how my plot looks like
[candlestick + hlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlNg7.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:  Set `returnfig=True` to gain [access to the Figure and Axes objects](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects), then use matplotlib's [`Axes.text()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) or [`Axes.annotate()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) to label your hlines:

```py
hlines=dict(hlines=clusters_centers,colors=['blue'],linestyle='-.')

fig, axlist = mpf.plot(hloc,hlines=hlines,
                       ylabel='Price',type='candle', 
                       style='binance',returnfig=True)

x = len(hloc)
for y in cluster_centers:
    axlist[0].annotate(str(y),(x,y))

mpf.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for