# Adding arrows to mpf finance plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, mplfinance

I am trying to add an arrow on a given date and price to mpf plot. To do this i have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd, mplfinance as mpf, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

db = yf.download(tickers='goog', start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=7), end= datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m")
db = db.dropna()
a = db['Close'][31:32]
test =  mpf.make_addplot(a, type='scatter', markersize=200, marker='^')
mpf.plot(db, type='candle', style= 'charles', addplot=test)
```

But it is producing the following error:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Could you please advise how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is to add an arrow to the title of the question, you can add it in the way shown in @Daniel Goldfarb's [How to add value of hlines in y axis using mplfinance python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68712666/how-to-add-value-of-hlines-in-y-axis-using-mplfinance-python). I used this answer to create a code that meets the end goal. As you can see in the answer, the way to do this is to get the axis and then add an annotation for that axis, where `31` is the date/time index and `a[0]` is the closing price.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

db = yf.download(tickers='goog', start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=7), end= datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m")
db = db.dropna()
a = db['Close'][31:32]

#test =  mpf.make_addplot(a, type='scatter', markersize=200, marker='^')
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(db, type='candle', style= 'charles', returnfig=True)#addplot=test

axlist[0].annotate('X', (31, a[0]), fontsize=20, xytext=(34, a[0]+20),
                   color='r', 
                   arrowprops=dict(
                       arrowstyle='->',
                       facecolor='r',
                       edgecolor='r'))
                    
mpf.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please advise how can i replace 31 with a datetime index for `x` in the plot ?

Comment: I also tried to use the date/time index without success. I checked the official reference and it says the value used is a float value, so using mdates.date2num() to convert it did not work. I guess I will have to get the index from the date and time I want to set from the dataframe. `db.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp('2022-02-16 12:05:00-0500', tz='America/New_York'))`-> `31`

Comment: See this:[https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html)

Answer (score 3):

The data passed into `mpf.make_addplot()` *must be the same length* as the dataframe passed into `mpf.plot()`.   To plot only some points, the remaining points must be filled with nan values (`float('nan')`, or `np.nan`).

You can see this clearly [in the documentation](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb) at cell `**In [7]**` (and used in the following cells).  See there where the signal data is generated as follows:

```py
def percentB_belowzero(percentB,price):
    import numpy as np
    signal   = []
    previous = -1.0
    for date,value in percentB.iteritems():
        if value < 0 and previous >= 0:
            signal.append(price[date]*0.99)
        else:
            signal.append(np.nan)  # <- Make `nan` where no marker needed.
        previous = value
    return signal
```

Note: alternatively the signal data can be generated by first initializing to all nan values, and then replacing those nans where you want your arrows:

```py
signal = [float('nan')]*len(db)
signal[31] = db['Close'][31:32]
test =  mpf.make_addplot(signal, type='scatter', markersize=200, marker='^')
...
```

Comment: I was curious about the title of the question, so I added an annotated version. I can do most of the work with these two approaches.